# ¿Cómo puedo sacar de la matriz 5x4, una la fila con el número menor y una columna que contenga el número mayor?

Tags: c++

Creé una matriz que crea numero aleatorios de 5x4, y me saca el numero mayor y el menor adentro de la matriz. Ahora lo que tengo que hacer es que al final me saque la fila con el numero mayor y la columna con el numero menor, ¿saben cómo podría hacer eso?

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){

    srand(time(NULL));

    int matriz[5][4];
    cout<<"Llenando"<<endl;
    for(int f=0; f<5; f++){
        for(int c=0; c<4; c++){
            matriz[f][c]=100 + rand() % (200-100);
        }
    }
    cout<<" \n Los datos ingresados fueron: "<<endl;
    for(int f=0;f<5;f++){
        for(int c=0;c<4;c++){
            cout<<"["<<matriz[f][c]<<"]";
        }
        cout<<endl;
    } 

    int mayor=0;
    int menor=0;
    menor=matriz[0][0];
    mayor=matriz[0][0];
    for(int f=0;f<5;f++){
        for(int c=0;c<4;c++){
            if(mayor<matriz[f][c]){
                mayor=matriz[f][c];
            }else if(menor>matriz[f][c]){
                menor=matriz[f][c];
            }
        }
    }
    cout<<"\nLa columna con el numero mayor es de: "<<mayor<<endl;
    cout<<"\nLa fila con el numero menor es de: "<<menor<<endl;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reduce las filas y columnas al valor máximo de cada una de ellas:

```
 17 18 19 20
  ^  ^  ^  ^
  |  |  |  |
  1  2  3  4 -> 4
  8  5  6  7 -> 8
 11 12  9 10 -> 12
 14 15 16 13 -> 16
 17 18 19 20 -> 20
```

Para ello, crea unas formaciones que guarden esos datos (ojo, estamos asumiendo que no habrán números negativos):

```
int mayor_fila[5] = {0};
int mayor_columna[4] = {0};
```

Y guarda los máximos donde corresponda:

```
for (int y = 0; y != 5; ++y)
    for (int x = 0; x != 4; ++x)
        mayor_fila[y] = std::max(mayor_fila[y], matriz[y][x]);

for (int x = 0; x != 4; ++x)
    for (int y = 0; y != 5; ++y)
        mayor_columna[x] = std::max(mayor_columna[x], matriz[y][x]);
```

Una vez lo tengas, sólo debes buscar el índice de la columna con el número mayor. Para el menor usa `std::min`, ten en cuenta que para buscar el mínimo deberás inicializar las formaciones al valor máximo entero.